# Android two way binding with Integer type(Livedata)

Tags: android, android-livedata, two-way-binding

I'm having some issue that two way binding with an Integer data type.

**ViewModel**

```
var saleType: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(1)
var saleDetail: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)
var salePrice: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)
var saleRate: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)
var printAmount: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(1)
```

**layout.xml**

```
<data>
    <import type="com.package.utils.DataBindingConverters" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.package.ViewModel" />
</data>
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
   android:id="@+id/sale_detail_input"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
   android:gravity="right"
   android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
   android:inputType="number"
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:maxLines="1"
   app:inputContent="@={DataBindingConverters.convertIntegerToString(viewModel.saleDetail)}"
                        />
```

**DataBindingConverters**

```
class DataBindingConverters {

    companion object {
        @InverseMethod("convertStringToInteger")
        @JvmStatic
        fun convertStringToInteger(value: String): Int? {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(value)) {
                return null
            }
            return value.toIntOrNull()
        }
        @InverseMethod("convertIntegerToString")
        @JvmStatic
        fun convertIntegerToString(value: Int?): String {
            return value?.toString() ?: ""
        }
    }

}
```

It occurs error like this

```
cannot find method convertIntegerToString(java.lang.String) in class com.package.utils.DataBindingConverters
```

I thought it would be good to process the value for IntegerToString in two-way binding, but I get an error that can't find a method.

In two-way binding, is there any other way to handle Integer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `app:inputContent` does, but using `android:text` on the `TextInputEditText` should be enough:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    ...
    android:text="@={ viewModel.salePriceString }"/>
```

Now you wonder what is `salePriceString`. It should be your 2-way binding liveData, and because `android:text` requires `String`, `salePriceString` typing would be `LiveData<String>`. Modify your viewModel to:

```
val salePriceString = MutableLiveData<String?>(0.toString())
```

Now every time you edit the text (by user input) in the `TextInputEditText`, your `salePricesString` will get updated with the new text. And anytime you update your `salePriceString` through code, the text of your `TextInputEditText` will update accordingly. For the latter case, if you want to update your `salePriceString` with a value of 500 for example, you would do `salePriceString.postValue(500.toString())`. And if you want to get the `Int` value from `salePriceString` in your code, just do `salePriceString.value?.toIntOrNull()`.

The next steps are optional, but if you want a convenient way to get the `Int` value without using `salePriceString.value?.toIntOrNull()` every time, modify your viewModel a bit further:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
...

val salePriceString = MutableLiveData<String?>(0.toString())
// add conversion to LiveData<Int>
val salePrice = Transformations.map(salePriceString) { priceString ->
    priceString?.toIntOrNull()
}
```

`salePrice` now contains the `Int` value of `salePriceString`, and is automatically updated every time `salePriceString` changes. `salePrice` is a `LiveData`, so you can observe it the same way you would observe `salePriceString`, but instead of `salePriceString`, you have the `Int` value ready in `salePrice`.

A final step is to observe `salePrice` somewhere in the code, most logically on the fragment that your viewModel is attached to:

```
viewModel.salePrice.observe(this, {}) // this, or viewLifecycleOwner, depending on your use case
```

You need to observe it, even if you then do nothing with the value. It is because `Transformation.map` is a bit strange one, the `LiveData` created by it won't go "live" unless there exists an observer for it. That means that until `salePrice` is observed by some observer, you won't get any value from it, i.e. `salePrice.value` would always be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way of using two-way data binding is the recommended way by Google as a link below.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#converters

The only problem in your code might be using @InverseMethod annotation in both of functions.
In the argument of the @InverseMethod annotation requires the name of the inverse function. And you don't need to add @InverseMethod annotation in both functions.
So the code should be modified as below.

```
@InverseMethod("convertIntegerToString")
@JvmStatic
fun convertStringToInteger(value: String): Int? {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(value)) {
        return null
    }
    return value.toIntOrNull()
}

@JvmStatic
fun convertIntegerToString(value: Int?): String {
    return value?.toString() ?: ""
}
```